# element not found when using xpath in angular site

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a angular website and I am trying to automate it using Selenium/Java. I know protractor is more easy for angular sites but I wish to use selenium.

I have been using "contains" keyword in the xpath to find elements as there are no unique id's available.

The element I am facing problem with is in the attached image circled in red. When I search the console with the xpath as shown in the image, the element is highlighted. But when I use it in the code I get the element not found error.

Is there a better way to handle this and why I am getting the error. I already have a wait condition.

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div class="status-selector ng-isolate-scope" fm-select="" 
     fm-select-options="::IssueDetailsCtrl.issue.allowedIssueStatuses" 
     fm-disabled="!IssueDetailsCtrl.issue.permissions.editStatus" 
     fm-model="IssueDetailsCtrl.issue.status" 
     fm-change="IssueDetailsCtrl.updateStatus()">
  <div class="fm-select undefined selected" ng-class="getStyle()" tabindex="" 
       ng-keyup="handleKeys($event)" ng-keydown="handleKeyDown($event)" style="">
    <div class="fm-select-title" ng-click="toggleVisibility()" 
         ng-class="{&quot;fm-select-title-highlighted&quot;: 
                   isOpen, &quot;fm-select-disabled&quot;: fmDisabled }">
      <div class="selected-item-icon" ng-class="selectedOption.imageClass"></div>
      <span class="ng-binding">Open</span>
    </div>
    <!-- ngIf: isOpen -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fm-select undefined selected" ng-class="getStyle()" tabindex="" 
     ng-keyup="handleKeys($event)" ng-keydown="handleKeyDown($event)" style="">
  <div class="fm-select-title" ng-click="toggleVisibility()" 
       ng-class="{&quot;fm-select-title-highlighted&quot;: 
                 isOpen, &quot;fm-select-disabled&quot;: fmDisabled }">
    <div class="selected-item-icon" ng-class="selectedOption.imageClass"></div>
    <span class="ng-binding">Open</span>
  </div>
  <!-- ngIf: isOpen -->
</div>
<div class="fm-select-title" ng-click="toggleVisibility()" 
     ng-class="{&quot;fm-select-title-highlighted&quot;: 
               isOpen, &quot;fm-select-disabled&quot;: fmDisabled }">
  <div class="selected-item-icon" ng-class="selectedOption.imageClass"></div>
  <span class="ng-binding">Open</span>
</div>
<div class="selected-item-icon" ng-class="selectedOption.imageClass"></div>
<span class="ng-binding">Open</span>
```

Wait condition:

```
 public void waitAndClickElement(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean clicked = false;
        int attempts = 0;
        while (!clicked && attempts < 20) {
            try {
                this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
                System.out.println("Successfully clicked on the WebElement: " + "<" + element.toString() + ">");
                clicked = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to wait and click on WebElement, Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                Assert.fail("Unable to wait and click on the WebElement, using locator: " + "<" + element.toString() + ">");
            }
            attempts++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share the code in text format instead of a image. So that we can easily provide you the solution.

Comment: Try to [wait for element to appear in DOM](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Comment: @Mohan, There are several `Open` in your given HTML, please narrow down to the exact one by DevTool, then remove redundant HTML in  question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use explicit wait in this case :

```
new WebDriver(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding' and text()='Open']"))).click();
```

**Or**  :

You can use this Xpath also :

```
//div[@class='selected-item-icon']/following-sibling::span[text()='Open' and @class='ng-binding']
```

Comment: The second xpath worked!! thanks. Can you please tell how did you derive at this?

Comment: @Mohan : the intended span is basically sibling of  div with class selected-item-icon. basically it's a following sibling , find more about xpath at : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 1):

Your app is Angular App and the button is dynamically attached to the DOM Tree only when certain condition satisfied by Angular `ng-if`, so need to wait Angular compile the HTML of the button before it attached to the DOM Tree.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

WebElement ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//div/span[text()='Open']"))
);

ele.click();
```